# Pinch to zoom got harder in MacOS 10.13.3 on MBP 2015

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra

After the latest system update [10.13.3 (17D102)] on my MBP 2015 I mentioned that some of my touchpad settings were reset to default. After fixing them I mentioned that all the gestures work again except of pinch to zoom which is hard to invoke. It's kind of frustrating. Does anyone have the very same problem?

Sorry for posting here, but the official Apple community forum fails to register me with *An unexpected error has occurred*.

Is it just me or did they change something?

Comment: Sometimes it just stops working completely for me on a TouchBar MBP :-|